# How to get all the rules defined in Sonar?

Tags: sonarqube

I am new to Sonar, in our project we are using SonarQube. Please tell the steps to get all the rules defined.

Answer (score 0):

In what format? You can view them all using the [rule search interface](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules):

Or get them as JSON using the [rule search api](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation/api/rules/search)